# Include custom text in captcha code generated by ImageString

Tags: php

I would like to have the ImageString in this script (that generates a captcha code) return the 5 digit numeric captcha code plus the text "is the code" (to help confuse spambots). Where would I modify this code to include my custom text in the image that is generated?

Thanks for any help on this.

```
<?php

session_start();
$md5_hash = md5(rand(0,99999)); 
$security_code = substr($md5_hash, 25, 5); 
$enc = md5($security_code);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $enc;

$width = 165;
$height = 30; 

$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 200, 200, 200);

ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $white); 
ImageString($image, 10, 7, 7, $security_code, $black); 

header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
ImagePng($image);
ImageDestroy($image);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps change

```
$security_code = substr($md5_hash, 25, 5);
```

to

```
$security_code = substr($md5_hash, 25, 5); 
$security_code .= " is the code";
```

That will append your text onto the string, being passed into `ImageString()`. Try that & see how you go. You might want to increase the image width, as well.

One alternative: if your custom CAPTCHA's weak, you could go with a library -- which might be more secure, and provide you with updates & increased security as new versions are released.

I used SecurImage -- http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Comment: Brilliant! That did it. Your help is much appreciated Thomas. Have a great night.